# What is the word for when a behavior is disliked in another because a person sees the behavior in themselves

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word to describe someone who doesn't like the behavior of someone because that same behavior is in them

e.g. "I hate my tendency to refuse social interaction, hence I also hate other people who act the same way"

Comment: Related (though not a duplicate): [Expression for two people whose similar personalities makes it difficult for them to get along](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193009/expression-for-two-people-whose-similar-personalities-makes-it-difficult-for-the)

Answer (score 3):

You're referring to psychological **projection**, where you transfer your own qualities to that of other people because you don't like your own qualities:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection)

> Psychological projection is a theory in psychology in which humans defend themselves against their own unconscious impulses or qualities (both positive and negative) by denying their existence in themselves while attributing them to others.[1] For example, a person who is habitually rude may constantly accuse other people of being rude. It incorporates blame shifting.
>
> According to some research, the projection of one's unconscious qualities onto others is a common process in everyday life.